# ARIMA model predicting seven days in the future

Tags: python, pandas, arima

Suppose that I have a time series that represents stock prices on a given day.

```
stock_price = [10, 15, 23, 24, 24, 23, 25, 25, 33, 30]
```

I want to build an ARIMA model that will be able to predict the stock price two days from now using the price from the past three days. So for instance, it can only use the information `stock_price[i:i+3]` in order to predict `stock_price[i+5]`.

In pandas, ARIMA takes three arguments `(a,b,c)`:

```
model = ARIMA(series, order=(a,b,c))
```

However, none of these are what I am trying to adjust.  I don't want ARIMA to just predict tomorrow's price.

Comment: Can you please post your entire code, especially the creation of the ARIMA model and the respective imports? I do not think that you use a pandas implementation of ARIMA. Are you sure that you do not use statsmodels?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
# Forecast dataframe - df
n_periods = 7
fc, confint = model.predict(n_periods=n_periods, return_conf_int=True)
index_of_fc = np.arange(len(df.value), len(df.value)+n_periods)

# make series for plotting purpose
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=index_of_fc)
lower_series = pd.Series(confint[:, 0], index=index_of_fc)
upper_series = pd.Series(confint[:, 1], index=index_of_fc)

# Plot
plt.plot(df.value)
plt.plot(fc_series, color='darkgreen')
plt.fill_between(lower_series.index, 
                 lower_series, 
                 upper_series, 
                 color='k', alpha=.15)

plt.title("Final Forecast ")
plt.show()
```

I learned Arima forecasting from here https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/
This helped me . hope this helps solves your problem as well